# Bluemix: cannot download starter code

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm starting learning about bluemix and I created an app using Liberty Java. 
When I tried to download starter code for importing to Eclipse, it only opened site https://console.ng.bluemix.net/ on a new tab and no file is downloaded. I'm using Firefox on Linux.

Could someone help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your browser language in English or are you using another language?

Comment: Hi Alex! I'm using English as browser language.

Answer (score 2):

This was a known issue that has since been corrected. Please redeploy your application and you will be able to download the starter code for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this method to download the starter code.

The starter code of node-red is available in new UI experience. When you are on that page click on "Try the New Bluemix" on top bar. Then click on "Getting overview" tab. Here you can Download the Starter Code.